# How to call a query only on refetch

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I was wondering if there was a way to call a query in a react component without connecting the component with graphql, because it lead the component to launch the query the first time it mount.

So basically is there a way to avoid the default call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you manually need to control the query or mutation and not use the default behavior from the `graphql()` HOC, use [`withApollo`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html#withApollo). It injects a GraphQL API client object into your component as a prop.

The client has `.query` and `.mutate` as methods. So you can do `this.props.client.query(...)` in `componentDidMount`.

```
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';

class Thing extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.client.query(myQuery).then(data => {
            this.setState({ data });
        };
    }
}

export default withApollo(Thing);
```

Comment: You, I like you.

Comment: Edit : the import is import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo'